# Can't locate DBD/Oracle.pm in @INC

Tags: perl, module

I'm trying to connect to Oracle via DBI, but can't make it work.

My setup:

```
# cat /proc/version 
Linux version 2.6.18-194.el5 (mockbuild@ca-build10.us.oracle.com) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)) #1 SMP Mon Mar 29 20:06:41 EDT 2010
# uname -i 
i386
# perl -v 
This is perl, v5.8.8 built for i386-linux-thread-multi 
<...>
# echo $ORACLE_HOME
/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client
```

I'm trying to connect using this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# dbi.pl
use warnings;
use strict;
use DBI;

$ENV{ORACLE_HOME}="/usr/lib/oracle/12.1";
$ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH}="/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client/lib";
$ENV{NLS_LANG}="american_america.CL8MSWIN1251";

my $user='user';
my $pw='pw';
my $host='servername';
my $port='1521';
my $SID = 'SID';
my $source = "dbi:Oracle:$host;sid=$SID;port=$port";

my $dbh=DBI->connect($source,$user,$pw,{PrintError=>0,AutoCommit=>0,RaiseError=>1}) or die "Oracle:$DBI::errstr\n";
```

And when I'm trying to execute it I'm getting an error:

```
#  ./dbi.pl
install_driver(Oracle) failed: Can't locate DBD/Oracle.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .) at (eval 3) line 3.
Perhaps the DBD::Oracle perl module hasn't been fully installed,
or perhaps the capitalisation of 'Oracle' isn't right.
Available drivers: DBM, ExampleP, File, Proxy, Sponge, mysql.
 at ./dbi.pl line 21
```

I tried to reinstall DBD-Oracle:

```
root@hostname:/tmp/DBD-Oracle-1.66# perl Makefile.PL
Using DBI 1.52 (for perl 5.008008 on i386-linux-thread-multi) installed in /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBI/

Configuring DBD::Oracle for perl 5.008008 on linux (i386-linux-thread-multi)

Remember to actually *READ* the README file! Especially if you have any problems.

Installing on a linux, Ver#2.6
Using Oracle in /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client
DEFINE _SQLPLUS_RELEASE = "1201000100" (CHAR)
Oracle version 12.1.0.1 (12.1)

        Unable to locate an oracle.mk or other suitable *.mk
        file in your Oracle installation.  (I looked in
        /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client/rdbms/demo/demo_xe.mk /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client/rdbms/demo/demo_rdbms32.mk /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client/rdbms/demo/demo_rdbms.mk /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client/rdbms/lib/ins_rdbms.mk /usr/share/oracle/12.1/client/demo.mk under /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client)

        The oracle.mk (or demo_rdbms.mk) file is part of the Oracle
        RDBMS product.  You need to build DBD::Oracle on a
        system which has one of these Oracle components installed.
        (Other *.mk files such as the env_*.mk files will not work.)
        Alternatively you can use Oracle Instant Client.

        In the unlikely event that a suitable *.mk file is installed
        somewhere non-standard you can specify where it is using the -m option:
                perl Makefile.PL -m /path/to/your.mk

        See the appropriate README file for your OS for more information and some alternatives.

     at Makefile.PL line 1187.
root@hostname:/tmp/DBD-Oracle-1.66#  ls /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client/
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Sep 24 13:23 bin/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Sep 24 13:23 lib/
root@hostname:/tmp/DBD-Oracle-1.66#
```

So, I don't have this 'rdbms' directory, because I installed instantclient. Is there any way to make it work without installing a database?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will fix this specific issue, but in general I would recommend using a tool like [cpanm](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/App-cpanminus-1.7001/bin/cpanm) to install CPAN modules, since it will handle dependencies for you. Once installed, run like this: `cpanm DBD::Oracle`

Comment: Make sure that all of the same environment vars are set when you're building `DBD::Oracle` as you're setting in your script. Setting them in the shell would be sensible.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: While cpanm is great at installing CPAN dependencies, DBD::Oracle depends on libraries/drivers external to Perl being properly installed and configured.  Unfortunately it's been a few years since I've don this on Linux.

Comment: anyway, I decided to use php instead (although I never worked with it). oci_connect works fine

Answer (score 1):

Recent full oracle database installs don't install all the bits you need for DBD::Oracle. I'm sorry but I cannot remember the name of the optional bit you need to install. However, an alternative (and a much easier one) is to download Oracle instant client "basic", "sdk" and "sqlplus", unzip them somewhere and point your LD_LIBRARY_PATH at that. It also makes you independent of the current Oracle database install which means if your dba upgrades it (or part of it) you don't need to think about rebuilding DBD::Oracle.

BTW, setting your LD_LIBRARY_PATH in your perl script won't work - it is too late.

Comment: Hi! What do you mean by "too late" ? Where it should be specified then?

Comment: You need to set it before you run your perl script.

Comment: @Alexander Setting it in a "wrapper" shell script will work.  Better yet, just put it in your login script.

Comment: Small note: On Windows the directory needs to be in PATH.  Not directly applicable to OP, but worth documenting...

Answer (score 1):

in my case this solved the problem:

```
     perl -MCPAN -e shell
      get DBD::Oracle
      quit

     cd ~/.cpan/build/DBD-Oracle***
     export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib
     export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/
     perl Makefile.PL
     make
        make install
```

Answer (score 1):

solved using : sudo cpan -i DBD::Oracle

Answer (score 0):

Hi did you set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? According to the [docs](https://metacpan.org/module/PYTHIAN/DBD-Oracle-1.66/lib/DBD/Oracle/Troubleshooting/Linux.pod), Makefile.PL should work with instant client now, but this is the only option I see that you have not followed (or at least shown that you have followed).

Comment: Yes, it is in the .bash_profile: 
`export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client`
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib`